# Post SUPEE-6778 patch installation

Tags: magento

Should installing the SUPEE 6778 patch automatically upgrade to 1.9.2.2
as in my admin area it still shows 1.9.2.1

The patch application was a success, so wondering if there are any other steps i need to take. 
If so can i just use the connect manager to upgrade? 
or are they any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

No, patches in Magento are only specific patch changes to files in the current version and do not increment the Magento version number.

If you want a full version upgrade to increment the version number, you must do a full version upgrade.

You have two ways of upgrading, they've been discussed extensively in other questions in this section.

1. Use Magento Connect, which can have issues where it only does a partial upgrade, and often needs file/ownership permissions messed with so it will complete properly, which must immediately be reset back for site security.
2. Use the downloadable full install archive which allows you to upgrade either by SFTP uploading the contents (takes a long time, can suffer timeouts) or by uploading the entire file and dearchiving it on top of your current installation to replace all of Magento's application files.